# What does Egit mean with the number in parenthesis in Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

What is meant by EGit when it displays a number in parenthesis in Package Explorer next to the project name, and a source folder name, but nowhere below?

e.g. notice the number (16):

[image]

I have checked out a tag from GIT (HEAD detached state). I don't have any local changes - neither committed or uncommitted.

If that's of relevance, it's a Gerrit repository, in Eclipse Kepler SR1 (Build id: 20130919-0819)

And I don't see a match with the configuration (I am using the default one) under Preferences | Team | GIt | Label Decorations | Projects:

```
  {dirty:>} {name}  [{repository} {branch}{ branch_status}]
```

Comment: Now I am thinking, maybe it has nothing to do with Git? It might be some generic Eclipse thing. But on the other hand - I have never seen a number like this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not from EGit.

Note that it's also on `src/main/java`. I would guess it's from Findbugs or Checkstyle or another plug-in.

Comment: Bingo! It's from Findbugs. I thought I have ruled out that option before, as I didn't see any matching Findbugs entry in the Problems view. But now after your comment I've checked and there is. Maybe a clean happened in between. I don't know. Anyway, mystery solved. Thanks!